Grafana behind Azure Application Gateway
I have an Azure Container Apps environment which is connected to a VNET which runs mostly internal workload containers (on an internal domain).
But some containers must be publicly available. This is done by using the Azure Application Gateway (with a public domain). This works fine for most containers, but not for a grafana container.
When connecting to the grafana UI on the public domain, I can login but cannot change any setting. I get an "origin not allowed" error. This looks like a CORS error.
When searching on this error I see that setting the following enviroment variables for the grafana container can solve this:
  {  
    name: 'GF_SERVER_ROOT_URL'
    value: https://[publicdomain].com
  }
  {
    name: 'GF_LIVE_ALLOWED_ORIGINS'
    value: '*,https://*.[publicdomain].com,wss://*.[publicdomain].com,http://*.[publicdomain].com'
  }
  {  
    name: 'GF_SERVER_DOMAIN'
    value: '[publicdomain].com'
  }

But unfortunately this doesn't work. There are also solution which states that the host header must be set to the public domain with a rewrite rule in the application gateway.
This is not possible because the backend setting already rewrites the host to the internal domain name to point to the correct container app. What are other options using the same infrastructure?

After some digging I found out that that creating a X-Forwarded-Host rewrite rule with the new domain in Azure Application Gateway and together with setting this enviroment variable:
{
  name: 'GF_SECURITY_CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS'  
  value: '[publicdomain].com'
}

did the trick.
